# Как в С# разбить строку на две переменные по разделителю?

Tags: c#

Как в С# разбить строку на две переменные по разделителю?
есть строка `kek:kek4chanmemamoral` Надо обрезать все до `:` и забить это в первую переменную , а остальное в вторую:

```
var 1 = kek; 
var 2 = kek4chanmemamoral;
```

Comment: Хотя бы примерно: что этими магическими словами автор хотел выразить?

Comment: есть строка kek:kek4chanmemamoral надо сделать var 1 = kek ; var 2  = kek4chanmemamoral;

Comment: а условия получения строки гарантируют что первые три символа являются первой переменной? или просто разбить строку при помощи символа ":"?

Comment: ссорян что не обьяснил правильно. Надо обрезать все до : и забить это в первую переменную , а остальное в вторую

Comment: Вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread273251.html

Comment: @JonCina1337 Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос, нажав кнопку "править"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно при помощи конструкции string.Split():

```
string text = "kek:kek2cheburek";

string[] words= text.Split(new char[]{':'}); 
// new char[] - массив символов-разделителей. Как меня поправили в 
// комментариях, в данном случае достаточно написать text.Split(':')

string first = words[0];
string second = words[1];

Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(second);
```

В этом коде мы создаём массив строк words, забиваем его содержимым строки, разбитым знаком ":".  Если вставить два двоеточия - будет три элемента, вставь три двоеточия в строку - будет 4 и т.д.

Надеюсь понятно расписал.

Comment: а зачем `new char[]{':'}` если  достаточно `text.Split(':');` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Верно, new char[]{} был взят из примера с несколькими знаками разделителями. Не прибрал, но вдруг автору пригодится )

Comment: @Garrus_En: а несколько разделителей можно так: `text.Split(':', ';', ',')`.

Comment: @VladD да по всякому можно :D

Answer (score 0):

Можно при помощи регулярных выражений, но это, лично для меня, более сложный способ, в отличии от цикла и substring.

```
String MyString = "FirstPart:SecondPart"; 
for (int i=0; i<MyString.Length,i++) 
if (compare(MyString[i],":")==0) 
{
String NewString=SubString(0,i);
String NewString2=SubString(i,MyString.Length-i); 
break; 
}
```

Comment: Переменные `NewString` и `NewString2` объявлены внутри цикла, поэтому видны только в нём. Извне блока к ним нет доступа.