# C# | Разделить строку на массив

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, строки

```
Вход: "qwerty!@#$%^?;sec;??"
Выход: [0] = qwerty!@#$%^?   
[1] = sec
[2] = ??
```

Comment: Принцип нужно словами прописать (вроде, разбить строку по символу),  это не сайт загадок

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в С# разбить строку на две переменные по разделителю?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667840/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a1-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать функцию `String.Split()`:

```
string str = "qwerty!@#$%^?;sec;??";
string[] strList = str.Split(';');
```

Описание String.Split: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Зачем сплитить в массив и преобразовывать потом в List, такой, вроде, не было задачи, зачем лишнее действие. Да и автор может подумать, что нужно делать именно так и никак иначе... Ну и не мешало бы дополнить, хотя бы ссылкой на MSDN с документацией по методу `string.Split()`

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо за замечания )