# Вывод нескольких данных в textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

дорогие форумчане. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при вводе какого-либо числа у меня выводится только одно значение true/false. Пишет ошибку Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "int" в "string[]".
А как мне реализовать такую вещь, чтобы при вводе числа в textbox у меня выводилось несколько цифр и значения true/false. Когда ввожу в void Prostie ввод Prost - как раз таки вводится только одно значение, а мне надо чтобы там был ввод Prosti. Заранее спасибо.

```
    static bool Prost(int number)
    {
        if (number < 2) return false;
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(number); i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void Prosti(string[] args)
    {
        int N;
        N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
        {
            if (Prost(i))
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + ",");
            }
        }
    }
   void Prostie()
    {

        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(Prosti(int.Parse(textBox3.Text)));

    }
```

Comment: Как это у вас вообще компилируется? `Prosti` возвращает `void`, `Convert.ToString(Prosti(...` не должно вовсе компилироваться.

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что можно было просто написать "как мне из строки 1 2 3 4 5 получить string[]?" А то нагородили тут, ей богу, фиг поймешь, еще и названия `Prostie`, `Prosti`, `Prost`, к этому еще диссонанс в виде `winforms` + `TextBox` + `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в С# разбить строку на две переменные по разделителю?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667840/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a1-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Вангую, функция `Prosti` — переименованный `Main` консольной программы (`Console.ReadLine` в том же классе, что и `textBox4.Text`? `static` + игнорируемые `args` туда же)

Comment: Что-то типо того, нашел в инете TextBoxStreamWriter, чтобы у меня выводилась консоль в textbox. Ибо, к сожалению не понял, каким образом можно было выводить по нормальному textbox.

Comment: Тупо найти в инете плохо, вы должны ещё и понимать, что вы нашли. Например, важна разница между возвращаемым значением и побочным эффектом.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку в виде дубликата вопроса, буду изучать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда задаете вопрос, пишите в первую очередь, что должен делать ваш код, а уже потом пишите что он на самом деле делает. Если это учебное задание, то дополнительно ко всему что выше, можно еще написать текст самого задания.

```cs
// определяет, простое число или нет
private bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    if (number < 2)
        return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= (int)Math.Sqrt(number); i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// возвращает строку, содержащую последовательность простых чисел от 2 до N через запятую
private string GetPrimeNumbers(int n)
{
    List<int> primeNumbers = new List<int();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (IsPrime(i))
            primeNumbers.Add(i);
    }
    return string.Join(", ", primeNumbers);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out int number) && number >= 2)
        textBox4.Text = GetPrimeNumbers(number);
    else
        textBox4.Text = "Нужно ввести целое положительное число от 2 до N";
}
```

Comment: Да, понял Вас, буду в след.раз подробнее обьяснять. Прошу прощения.